# How to copy 1 column from one db to another db in a range of rows

Tags: mysql, copy

I have database1 with table1 and column1 and I have database2 with table2 and column2

I would like to copy the values from the database1 (from column1) to database2 column2

This is my try but it's not working

```
INSERT INTO database2.table2 (column2 WHERE id BETWEEN 1 and 43
SELECT column1 FROM database1.table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
INSERT INTO database1.table1 (column) 
SELECT contenido FROM reiconfe_negocio.existencias 
WHERE id BETWEEN 1 and 43
```

Comment: I need to specify the rows range in database2... I just edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You can connect two `databases` by using this way:

```
INSERT INTO database2.table2 (database2.table2.column2)
SELECT database1.table1.column2
FROM database1.table1 
WHERE database2.table2.column2 BETWEEN 1 and 43
```

You must need to use `database` and `alias` or full name as i used in query than you can copy the values from one `database` to another one.

Comment: Replace 1 to 2 .. anywy I have updated the answet @davidm